# What is network renderer?

Tags: rendering, add-on, network

There's this addon called network renderer, and I have no idea what it does. I can't find it on the web.  So what is it?

Answer (score 11):

Blender's network renderer allows you to link to other PCs -- Apple, Windows, Linux -- and distribute your render job to many computers... speeding up the job overall... It is a job management tool to make rendering many frames faster, by spreading the work across multiple platforms.

Here's a good video on using network render and in setting up a render farm  in your office:
https://cgcookie.com/archive/setting-up-a-render-farm/

Comment: There is also [the wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender) for it.